# Android resource resolution algorithm

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, resources

I am quite familiar with the android docs on how to provide resources.

Yet I have some questions that I didn't find answered.

My resource folders use selectors on

- "Screen pixel density" (l,m,h,x,xx(dpi)),
- "Screen size"(small,normal,large,xlarge) and
- "Screen aspect"(long,notlong).

But I do not have all possible combinations of those.

So let's **suppose I have a xhdpi-notlong-large device**.

**How does android decide between** choosing the resources from

- res/drawable-xhpi
- res/drawable-large
- res/drawable-notlong

Given that **all of these folders contain the same drawable**. i.e. foo.png?

I was looking for documentation about the ranking of those selectors. If that does not exist i would like to see the algorithm that chooses the resource folder to understand how I have to provide them the best way.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch